# Cell content overlapping SWTableViewCell buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement `SWTableViewCell` into my `UITableView` with a custom cell from a xib-file. But the this that is happening is that the cell content is not swiped over to the left side like it should. As a result of this the content overlaps the buttons. See image:

[image: Content covers up SWTableViewCell buttons]

I have tried a numerous of things trying to get around this.
Here is my code from cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"PictureTableViewCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);

        PictureTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setCellHeight:cell.frame.size.height];
        cell.containingTableView = tableView;

        Image *tempImage = imagesArray[indexPath.row];

        cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:tempImage.image];
        cell.lblDescription.text = tempImage.image_description;
        NSLog(tempImage.image_description);

        cell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
        cell.delegate = self;

        return cell;
}
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.images = selectedReport.image;

    imagesArray = [self.images.allObjects mutableCopy];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];   

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PictureCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PictureTableViewCell"];

}
```

If anyone could help me with this I would be very grateful! 
Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Make sure all of your cell's content is added to the cell's `contentView` and not added directly to the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy Holy freaking jesus how on earth havn't I seen this. I love you thank you!

Comment: @rmaddy Why not post in a form of an answer so he can accept?